# Variación sobre el problema de la mochila en Programación Dinamica

Tags: java, algoritmos, optimización

estoy haciendo una pequeña variación del problema de la mochila en Programación Dinámica. Yo tengo el código en java completo en el caso de maximizar, pero me gustaría que en este caso minimizara. Se que hay que cambiar lo métodos getTipo (ya cambiado a minimizar), seleccionaAlternativa (ya cambiado a minimizar) y el getObjetivoEstimado (no se como hacerlo para que minimize) y el getObjetivo (tampoco se hacerlo para que minimize)
 Le adjunto el código:

```
public class ProblemaMochilaPD implements ProblemaPD<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>, Integer> {

    private static ProblemaMochilaPD problemaInicial;
    private static Integer capacidadInicial;
    private int index;
    private Double valorSolucion = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    public static List<Integer> multiplicidadesMaximas;
    public static List<ObjetoMochila> objetos;
    public static Integer numeroDeObjetos;


    public static ProblemaMochilaPD create(String fichero, Integer c) { 
        ProblemaMochila.leeObjetosDisponibles(fichero);
        ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos = ProblemaMochila.getObjetosDisponibles();
        ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos = ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.size();
        ProblemaMochilaPD.multiplicidadesMaximas = ProblemaMochila.getObjetosDisponibles()
                .stream().mapToInt(x->x.getNumMaxDeUnidades())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());          
        ProblemaMochilaPD.capacidadInicial = c;
        ProblemaMochilaPD.problemaInicial = new ProblemaMochilaPD(0, 0, 0.);
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.problemaInicial;
    }

    public static ProblemaMochilaPD create(int index,int pesoAcumulado,double valorAcumulado) {
        ProblemaMochilaPD p = new ProblemaMochilaPD(index, pesoAcumulado,valorAcumulado);
        return p;
    }

    private Integer pesoAcumulado;
    private Integer capacidadRestante;
    private Double valorAcumulado;


    private ProblemaMochilaPD(int index, int pesoAcumulado, double valorAcumulado) {
        this.index = index;
        this.pesoAcumulado = pesoAcumulado;
        this.capacidadRestante = capacidadInicial-this.pesoAcumulado;
        this.valorAcumulado = valorAcumulado;
    }   

    private Boolean constraints(Integer a) {
        return this.pesoAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getPeso() <= capacidadInicial;
    }   

    @Override
    public Tipo getTipo(){
        return Tipo.Min;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos-index+1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> getAlternativas() {
        List<Integer> ls = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, ProblemaMochilaPD.multiplicidadesMaximas.get(this.index))
                .filter(x->this.constraints(x))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.reverse(ls);
        return ls;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean esCasoBase() {
        return this.capacidadRestante == 0 ||  index == ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos-1;
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> getSolucionCasoBase() {
        Integer peso = objetos.get(index).getPeso();
        int num = Math.min(capacidadRestante/peso,objetos.get(index).getNumMaxDeUnidades()) ;
        Double val = (double) num*objetos.get(index).getValor();
        valorSolucion = val;
        return Sp.create(num, val);
    }

    @Override
    public ProblemaPD<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>, Integer> getSubProblema(Integer a, int np) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(np==0);
        Integer pesoAcumulado = this.pesoAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getPeso();
        Double valorAcumulado = this.valorAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getValor();
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.create(index+1,pesoAcumulado,valorAcumulado);
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> combinaSolucionesParciales(Integer a, List<Sp<Integer>> ls) {
        Sp<Integer> r = ls.get(0);
        Double valor = a*objetos.get(index).getValor()+r.propiedad;
        return Sp.create(a, valor);
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> seleccionaAlternativa(List<Sp<Integer>> ls) {
        Sp<Integer> r =ls.stream().filter(x -> x.propiedad != null).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
        valorSolucion = r!=null ? r.propiedad : Double.MIN_VALUE;
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumeroSubProblemas(Integer a) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Multiset<ObjetoMochila> getSolucionReconstruida(Sp<Integer> sp) {
        Multiset<ObjetoMochila> m = HashMultiset.create();
        m.add(ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.get(this.index), sp.alternativa);
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    public Multiset<ObjetoMochila> getSolucionReconstruida(Sp<Integer> sp, List<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>> ls) {
        Multiset<ObjetoMochila> m = ls.get(0);
        m.add(ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.get(this.index), sp.alternativa);
        return m;
    }


    @Override
    public Double getObjetivoEstimado(Integer a) {  
        return this.valorAcumulado+this.getCotaSuperiorValorEstimado(a);
    }

    @Override
    public Double getObjetivo() {
        return this.valorAcumulado+this.valorSolucion;
    }


    /**
     * @pre a está contenida en getAlternativas()
     * @param a Una alternativa de this
     * @return Una cota superior del valor de la solución del problema this si se escoge la alternativa a
     */
    public Integer getCotaSuperiorValorEstimado(Integer a){
        Double r = 0.;
        Double capacidadRestante = (double) (capacidadInicial-pesoAcumulado);
        Double nu =(double) a;
        int ind = this.index;
        while(true) {
            r = r+nu*objetos.get(ind).getValor();
            capacidadRestante = capacidadRestante-nu*objetos.get(ind).getPeso();
            ind++;
            if(ind >= objetos.size() || capacidadRestante <= 0.) break;
            nu = Math.min(multiplicidadesMaximas.get(ind),capacidadRestante/objetos.get(ind).getPeso());            
        } 
        return (int)Math.ceil(r);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((capacidadRestante == null) ? 0 : capacidadRestante
                        .hashCode());
        result = prime * result + index;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ProblemaMochilaPD))
            return false;
        ProblemaMochilaPD other = (ProblemaMochilaPD) obj;
        if (capacidadRestante == null) {
            if (other.capacidadRestante != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!capacidadRestante.equals(other.capacidadRestante))
            return false;
        if (index != other.index)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + index + ", "
                + capacidadRestante + ")";
    }
}
```

Les dajunto también la clase: ObjetoMochila, para que se pueda ver las propiedades que tienen los objetos.

```
public class ObjetoMochila implements Comparable<ObjetoMochila>{

    public static ObjetoMochila create(Integer valor,Integer peso, Integer countMax) {
        return new ObjetoMochila(valor, peso, countMax);
    }

    public static ObjetoMochila create(String s) {
        return new ObjetoMochila(s);
    }

    private static Integer nCodigo = 0;

    private Integer codigo;
    private Integer valor;
    private Integer peso;
    private Integer numMaxDeUnidades;

    ObjetoMochila(Integer valor, Integer peso, Integer countMax){
        this.codigo = nCodigo;
        nCodigo++;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.numMaxDeUnidades = countMax;
    }   
    ObjetoMochila(String s){        
        String[] v = s.split("[ ,]");
        Integer ne = v.length;
        if(ne != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Formato no adecuado en línea  "+s); 
        valor = new Integer(v[0]);
        peso = new Integer(v[1]);
        numMaxDeUnidades = new Integer(v[2]);
        this.codigo = nCodigo;
        nCodigo++;
    }   
    public Integer getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }
    public Integer getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public Integer getNumMaxDeUnidades() {
        return numMaxDeUnidades;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ObjetoMochila o) {
        int r = getRatioValorPeso().compareTo(o.getRatioValorPeso());
        if(r == 0){
            r = getCodigo().compareTo(o.getCodigo());
        }
        return r;
    }   
    public Double getRatioValorPeso() {
        return ((double)valor)/peso;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<"+codigo+","+valor+","+peso+","+numMaxDeUnidades+">";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ObjetoMochila))
            return false;
        ObjetoMochila other = (ObjetoMochila) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Y ... ... ¿cuál es la pregunta o cuál es el problema?

Comment: Que como hago para que minimice en vez de maximizar, que no se como seria el getObjetivo y getObjetivoEstimado, se que habria que hacer una cota minima en vez de maxima, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Nadie me puede ayudar?

Comment: Del segundo código que he pasado no hay que cambiar nada(son los atributos de los objetos de la mochila), solo del primero para que se pueda minimizar y tendria que ser en el getObjetivo o getObjetivoEstimado para sacar la solución, aparte de getTipo y del seleccionaAlternativa, pero estos dos últimos ya los tengo yo hecho, seria los getObjetivos los que habria que cambiar, pero no se como hacerlo. A ver si alguien me puede ayudar.